# Modulo question with negative

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$60-88  \equiv \,\,? \pmod 5$

$60-88 = -28$

Then what do I do?

Please tell me how to answer this question. Thanks.

Comment: Add $\, 30\equiv 0.$

Comment: -28 + 30 = 2 ? Please tell me how you got Zero

Comment: mod $\,5\!:\ \color{#c00}{5\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\, 30 = 6\cdot \color{#c00}5 \equiv 6\cdot \color{#c00}0\equiv 0,\,$ i.e. $30$ leaves remainder $0$ when divided by $5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a negative number, like $-28 \pmod 5$, all you really need to do keep adding the modulus, or an integer multiple of the modulus $m$, to the negative number until it is zero or in $\mathbb Z_m = \{0, 1, \cdots, m-1\}.\;$

In this case, we can add any multiple of the modulus $5$ to $-28$ until we obtain zero or a positive number, if you are looking to represent the equivalence class of $-28$ modulo $5$ with the least positive integer $x$, $\;x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

So given $$60 - 88 = -28 \equiv x\pmod 5\tag{1}$$ and wanting to find such a representative $x$, we know that $5k \equiv 0 \pmod 5$, and simply choose $k = 6$ as our multiple of $5$ so we have $$5 \cdot 6 = 30 \equiv 0 \pmod 5\tag{2}$$

Adding $(1), (2)$:

$$30 - 28 = 2 \equiv x \pmod 5$$

That is, $60 - 88 = - 28 \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

What this all means is that any multiple $n$ of 5, added to $2$ is congruent modulo $5$ to $2$, including $-28$: The solutionS to all $$x \equiv 2 \pmod 5 = \{x\mid x = 2 \pm 5n, n \in \mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: @ amWhy so the answer is 2 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The answer is $2$, but every multiple of 5 added to or subtracted from $2$ is also congruent to $2$, mod 5. but I suspect you are needing $2$, which is the least non-negative solution to your problem, mod 5.

Comment: @amWhy: Always providing helpful comments and descriptions ... +1

Comment: @amWhy 

50-99 = (mod 5) 

= -49 + 50

so answer is 1?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Nice work. Please feel free to accept helpful answers: just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 0):

As Key Ideas pointed in the comments...

$60-88  \equiv \,\,x \pmod 5$

$-28 \equiv \,\,x \pmod 5$

$-28+30 \equiv \,\,x+30 \pmod 5$

$2 \equiv \,\,x \pmod 5$

$x=5n-2$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$